# Apple's "On Demand resources" doesn't work in a first run on Flutter Application if using "flutter run" command

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, on-demand-resources

I have a flutter application for IOS, this application loads a zip file from Apple's ODR system (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/)

To have that working I've built a flutter package that loads the zip file using NSBundleResourceRequest and save it, then it returns to the flutter side the path of the saved zip.

Everything works fine if I run it directly from XCode.

However, if I uninstall the build and try to run it using "flutter run" command, it fails with the following error:

`"The requested application data doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600003f13c60 {Error Domain=_NSBundleResourceRequestErrorDomain Code=100 "No manifest found for bundle ID com.iosbuildtest.packagetest" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=No manifest found for bundle ID com.iosbuildtest.packagetest`

Then if I run it through xcode, and then, without uninstalling the application, I try to run again using "flutter run", it works normally.

Wondering what is difference between the flutter run build process vs xcode build.

btw, I've already tried to run "flutter clean" and "flutter build ios" before running the flutter run, problems still persists.